# $a_{n+1}=a_n^3-3a_n^2+3a_n.$ Find $a_1$ s.t. $(a_n)$ is convergent, and its limit

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

Consider the sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge1}$ defined by $a_1=a$ (a real number), and $a_{n+1}=a_n^3-3a_n^2+3a_n$. Find for which values of $a$ the sequence is convergent, and then find its limit.

I calculated between $a_{n+1}-a_n=a_n(a_n-1)(a_n-2)$ but I do not know what to do further. Can you help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: $a_{n+1}-1 = (a_n-1)^3$.

Comment: I found that too. But how does it help me?

Comment: You can derive a formula for general term from the equation.

Comment: @george_o: take $x_n=a_n-1$ and you get something much simpler

Answer (score 2):

If you do add $-1$ to both sides, you get $a_{n+1}-1=(a_n-1)^3$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now, if you change variables $b_n=a_n-1$, you get $$b_{n+1}=b_n^3,\quad  \forall n.$$
Now, look at the scheme:
$$b_2=b_1^3$$
$$b_3=b_2^3=(b_1^3)^3=b_1^{3^2}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$b_n=b_1^{3^{n-1}}, \quad \forall n.$$
We know that it converges iff $|b_1|<1$ or $|a-1|<1$, wich implies $0<a<2$.

PS: I forgot the cases when $b_1=1$ and $b_1=-1$ wich also converges

Comment: Hoa about $b_1 = -1$